# How to give multiple Class names with or condition in Coded UI search properties

Tags: automated-testing, c#, test-automation-framework, coded-ui-tests, css-selectors

```
 this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = ".class1 or .class2";
```

Comment: have you tried:  ".class1, .class2"    ?

Answer (score 1):

you could use the [FilterProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.filterproperties(v=vs.120).aspx) if it is supported by the technology you use to find your control.

FilterProperties works as a "Or" when SearchProperties works as a "And".

The code should be:

```
this.FilterProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = ".class1"
this.FilterProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = ".class2";
```

You can still combinated it with the SearchProperties (but for other properties otherwise the SearchProperties will have predominance on the FilterProperties).

```
this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "MyControl";
this.FilterProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = ".class1"
this.FilterProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = ".class2";
```